# Laravel response of type download corrup the file

Tags: laravel, xlsx

Users need to download files in `xlsx` and `pdf` format. I am using laravel 10

```
$headers = array(
            'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary',
            );

return response()->download('/file.xlsx', 'file.xlsx', $headers);
```

I test in the browser and in the mobile client, the situation is always the same. The file in `xlsx` format is downloaded, its size to the byte is the same as on the server, but the file is always damaged and cannot be opened. If I zip it into an archive, then it is downloaded in the same way, but it is also damaged, although its size exactly matches. tried different options for headers `Content-Type` and `Content-Transfer-Encoding` but they do not affect in any way, just do not understand why they are needed.  There are no problems with `pdf` files, they download and open correctly with any header options. I can't figure out what's going on, does anyone have any ideas on how to download the file in the `xlsx` format?

Comment: Why you need to define header ? You can simply download file

return response()->download('/file.xlsx', 'file.xlsx');

Comment: I have an error when opening the downloaded file and I thought that I would need to add a custom header. I tried different header options, but the error remains. Without header also error after opening the file, but the size of the downloaded file is 100% correct

Comment: Can you try from different browser?

Comment: Used several browsers on desktop, on console - сurl and wget then  android device and flutter dio http cleint. Еverywhere the same result. The files download successfully, correct size, but do not open. I thought it was protection in Excel, but for zip archives the same error. But for some reason the pdf opens fine

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `$headers`? I think `->download` adds the correct ones anyway

Comment: @apokryfos Same error, I tried different options but the result is the same.

Comment: Can you try with a normal text file where you know the content and check if that gets corrupted (and in what way)?

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks for the help, I broke my server with updates and couldn't check. Before giving the file to the user, you need to `ob_end_clean();` and then `ob_start();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried various `http header` options, but they did not affect. The solution that works is to add before sending the `xlsx` file to the user - call these two functions

```
 ob_end_clean();
 ob_start();

//Then use the laravel method which is for your situation, for example   

return response()->download('/file.xlsx');
```